# How to dispose connections when using multiple data contexts in Asp.net MVC 4 with entity framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, ado.net

I am using ADO.net SQL connection to my ASP.net MVC 4 project. I have used 8 data contexts. Entity Framework 6 is used. While I'm working on the project It hangs and gets 503 error.
I'm getting the following error message

> The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are
>   pending requests working on this transaction.

Comment: Are they being disposed of properly?

Comment: Can you share the code as that would be helpful in identifying the problem?